# The Area51 ten-question-per-site-proposal rule should be referenced in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, faq-update-request

I'm not taking issue with the policy - I see the value in encouraging everyone to post their 10 most relevant questions for each proposal (rather than just adding as many as they can think of to build up rep).   That said, it should be referenced in FAQ, much in the same way the 100 votes per day limit is.

Comment: you should change the title, it's not a 10 q/d but per proposal limit

Comment: @Tobias, you're right, thanks - revising.

Comment: This is true, but you might give them some time to implement just-announced features before you start the requests...

Comment: @Cat, it's not a demand; my assumption is that posts here help them identify issues, and they'll address them based on priority as they see fit.  I'd think you'd generally want to address one this simple sooner rather than later, to save time and noise  - one FAQ update may prevent numerous support e-mails, meta posts, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point.  It has been added: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: is that limit per day or for ever?