# Understanding Area 51 limit on number questions created for proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

> You've already created 11 questions for this proposal!

But no, I've created 11 questions *total*, spread across 6 different proposals.

---

Update: The message has changed to

> You've already created 5 questions for this proposal!

which is at least accurate. So now the question becomes, ["is this the actual limit?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52154/the-area51-ten-question-per-site-proposal-rule-should-be-referenced-in-the-faq)

Comment: I just saw this one, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  I can neither confirm nor deny the rumor that I hard-coded it to 11 and forgot to go back and implement the actual count.

Comment: Unit tests return green!  Release! :)